# Factorization of the energy/mass relation (as used to obtain the Dirac equation) applied to the invariant interval

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, dirac-equation

In considering the Klein-Gordon equation Dirac was examining the energy equation:

$$m^{2}c^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}P^{\mu}P^{\nu}$$

(though he only was considering the flat space case $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$. Rewriting the above as:

$$0=g_{\mu\nu}P^{\mu}P^{\nu}-m^{2}c^{2}$$

Proceeding to factor this Dirac obtained an expression like:

$$0=\left(\gamma_{\mu}P^{\mu}-mc\right)\left(\gamma_{\nu}P^{\nu}+mc\right)$$

Where $\left\{ \gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}\right\} =\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu}+\gamma_{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}=2g_{\mu\nu}$. This is entirely general, though in quantum theory, the $P^{\mu}$ would be replaced with their quantum operators acting on a wavefunction $\Psi$.

Continuing with the general case, choosing one factor or another leads one to the Dirac equation for either positive or negative mass solutions:

$$0=\left(\gamma_{\mu}P^{\mu}\pm mc\right)$$

In choosing either + or - I would think one would have to make the same choice (for consistency) in all other areas of spacetime geometry.

For example, the infinitesimal invariant interval is generally expressed as:

$$ds^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$$

The mathematical parallel to the first equation seems pretty straight forward:
$$0=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}-ds^{2}$$

$$0=\left(\gamma_{\mu}dx^{\mu}-ds\right)\left(\gamma_{\nu}dx^{\nu}+ds\right)$$
 however, in attempting to do this in another question of mine: ([Is the Invariant interval S between two points independent of the path taken?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298570/is-the-invariant-interval-s-between-two-points-independent-of-the-path-taken)) I was literally browbeaten by users. (This may have been due to my poor choice of wording)

My question is:

If the factorization of the first equation is soo completely accepted, then what is wrong with factoring the latter equation (i.e the interval)?

The answers I got didn't address any proper issues that I'm aware of, especially when compared to Dirac's factorization as above (If I took them at face value then the Dirac equation would be invalid ha!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up notation and actual algebraic operations. The metric is a section of the symmetric square of the cotangent bundle, which in turn is a factor of the symmetric algebra on this bundle. If you extend the scalars from the real numbers to the Clifford algebra of the scalars product in each point, you indeed can factorise the expression

$$g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu} =\left(\gamma_{\mu}dx^{\mu}\right)\left(\gamma_{\nu}dx^{\nu}\right)$$

as you did. Note that the $\gamma^\mu$ take values in a *different* Clifford algebra at every point. I guess one can find a parameterized matrix representation so that they become smooth matrix valued functions.

The problem is with your factorisation of $ds^2$. Unlike $m^2c^2$, which actually is a square, this is just notation. It seems to suggest that it is the square of some quantity $ds$, and moreover that this $ds$ actually is the differential of some function, but neither is true in general.

Where

$$m^{2}c^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}P^{\mu}P^{\nu}$$

Is an equation (with physical content),

$$ds^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$$

is the expansion of $ds^2$, which could just as well (or better) have been written $g$ (for example), in a local basis derived from a coordinate basis.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the old gravitation and they had a factorization in the beginning of the book, just got me thinking is all. Thanks again!

Comment: I was also looking at how you can use the shift operator to "move" some object over the manifold, which ended up making me go down this road.

Comment: I always thought that, for timelike motion, that $ds^2$ indeed can be factored as it represents proper time. I get that is not always perfectly defined of course

Comment: The lattermost equation in your answer you mention as being an expansion as opposed to the former equation. I always thought of mass as merely the magnitude of the momentum four vector, in this sense, aren't the momentum components just an expansion of it as well? sorry, honestly curious, sometimes I like to question the basics.

Comment: It was the fact that the two equations are composed of the conjugate variables of one another that even made me curious about this line of thought

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is wrong. $\gamma^{\mu} p_{\mu} \pm m=0$ is valid only as an operator equation. It is valid only when it acts on the on-shell field operator as in QFT, or on the particle state as in the Dirac equation.

Comment: Much appreciated. Can you steer me towards a reference or book that explains this?

Comment: @R.Rankin I am not aware of the literature that explains this. I suggest you just to think about the fact that $p_{\mu}$  and $\gamma^{\mu}$ are understood here as acting on some space, not defined invariantly of this space in contrast to $\mathrm{d} s^2$.

Comment: Almost any reference I look at (for example: https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/staff/academic/boyd/stuff/dirac.pdf equations 16-28) carry through the factorization just as I did above and don't mention it only applying to operator equations.

Comment: @R.Rankin It is by default. Dirac equation is an equation defining the state vector, so it is always on the right.